# The type or namespace name 'get' could not be found

Tags: c#, get, namespaces

My `get` is getting the error in the question, I have no clue what is wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace VanDusen_PracticeObjects
{
class MathFun
{
    int number1 = 4;
    int number2 = 4;
    int total = 0;


    public MathFun()
    {
    }

    public void MultiplyThem()
    {
        number1 = 2 * 2;
    }
    public void AddThem()
    {
         number2 = 2 + 2;
    }

    public MathFun(int innumber1, int innumber2)
    {
        number1 = innumber1;
        number2 = innumber2;
    }
    public int Number1;
    {
        get
        {
           return number1;
        }
        set
        {
           number1 = value;
        }
    }
    public int Number2;
    public int Total;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Number1` is a [`property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and has not semicolon so you should remove semicolon after this line:

```
public int Number1;
```

So:

```
public int Number1
{
    get { return number1; }
    set { number1 = value; }
}
```